# What does Hondo Eisuke mean when he says, "I think I stood up on the wrong leg as a child."

Tags: japanese-language, detective-conan

In Episode 462, Hondo Eisuke says, "I think I stood up on the wrong leg as a child."

[image: A picture of the scene of Hondo Eisuke as described above]

I tried searching for this idiom online but couldn't find anything, most likely because I was searching the english text that the translator put and not the Japanese. However, the Japanese is quick for my beginner ears, so I wasn't able to write it down.

Hondo is a rather unlucky guy, and this happened right after getting coffee poured on him, so from the context I'm assuming it has to do with bad luck but I'd like to know if there is more info I can read about this idiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation is incorrect but was probably trying to convey a joke on Hondo Eisuke's bad luck in this show since every time I see him, he seems to suffer from some sort of event.

Anyway, what he said here was "Bou to tsutate ita boku ga doji de noruma data desukara." which translates to something like "Me standing here and daydreaming being careless and slow is at fault here." if I do it without caring for English Grammar.

However what I would translate it as would be like "It was my fault for standing here daydreaming and thus being a careless idiot."